# SQLite: Get monthly, weekly or daily average of all entries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite database of records in this format:

```
date        location  temperature
1568463916  room 1    20.0
1568463916  room 2    25.0
1568463916  room 3    30.0
...
1568460316  room 1    15.5
1568460316  room 2    20.5
1568460316  room 3    21.3
```

Every hour three new records get inserted, one for every room.

For a monthly average this output is desired:

```
month  avg_temperature  location
01     21.333           room 1
01     24.5             room 2
01     19.0             room 3
...
12     20.4             room 1
12     31.31            room 2
12     13.37            room 3
```

The same query might be reused to get weekly averages (day 00-07) and daily averages (hour 00-23).

To get a monthly average, I'm assuming I will select:

- All records with `date` between `now` and `now - 1 year`
- Month of every record with `strftime(date, "unixepoch")` as `month`
- For every `location`, then for every `month` get `avg(temperature)`
- The result is `rooms*12` rows of average temperature of each room for each month

When I'm using the `GROUP BY` statement however, I'm only getting the last row of every month. What's the correct way to construct this kind of query?

This is the query I've tried:

```
SELECT strftime("%m", date, "unixepoch") month,
       avg(temperature) avg_temperature,
       location

FROM table

WHERE date > date("now", "unixepoch", "-1 year")
AND   date < date("now", "unixepoch")

GROUP BY location, month
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
select date(datetime(date, 'unixepoch'), 'start of month') as month,
       location,
       avg(temperature)
from t
group by date(datetime(date, 'unixepoch'), 'start of month') as month,
         location
order by month, location;
```

Comment: I've updated my post with a query I've tried initially. Can I use `group by month, location` instead of `group by date(...) as month, location`?

Comment: @www . . . Yes.  SQLite supports aliases in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I suppose `(datetime(date, 'unixepoch'), 'start of month')` does the same as `strftime('%m', date)`? I need to select an average value of records within every month of the past year for every `location` I have, so `month 01, avg 20.0, location room 1` will mean that in January, average temperature in room 1 was 20.0, however the values stored in the database are updated every hour.

Comment: @www . . . No, I don't think they are the same.